# Configuring Page Viewer To Refresh Sharepoint Page after clicking it

Tags: sharepoint

I have a set of items displayed in page viewer web parts that are from an external site.  In order for them to display login credentials for external site are needed.  I put the login page as the first web part (page viewer) on the sharepoint library.  how do I make it so that after login is completed the page refreshes automatically to now display the other web parts?

Comment: You may want to ask your question on the [SharePoint Stack Exchange](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: It will be good to also post some code, sample, screenshots to describe the issue better.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKrnU.png here is a pic of what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

it is bit tricky, since here cross domain comes into picture, but probably what you can do is, have a button where in you show that page viewer for login, and once clicked you have some kind of timer, which then refreshes the other page viewer urls. To refresh url is easy just reset the "src" attributes of iframes.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKrnU.png this is an idea of what im trying to do. not sure how to easily accomplish that nikunj. is there a way to determine that once in the top page viewer 'login' is clicked to refresh the rest of the frames?